# apex:inputfile file attachment 'FileName' and 'Blob' value always null

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to send Email with Attachment using  control, but the Value is always null.
The Email is sending successfully.

Here is my `Apex Controller`

```
public without sharing class SendMailClass{
   public transient Blob bl {get; set;}
   public String contentType {get; set;}
   public String fileName {get; set;}

   public void SendMail()
   {    
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email;
        string[] toAddresses = new string[]{};
        List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();

        Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();

        email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                             
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId('OWAID');          

        toAddresses.add('ToAddress');

        email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
         System.debug('--FileName--'+fileName); //NULL
         System.debug('--Blob--'+bl);//NULL
        if((fileName != null || fileName != '') && bl != null)
        {
                fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
                efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
                efa.setFileName(fileName);
                efa.setBody(bl);
                fileAttachments.add(efa);
                email.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
         }
         email.setPlainTextBody(""TEST Attachment);
         Messaging.SendEmailResult [] results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});

        if (!results[0].isSuccess())
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'The Email failed to send: '+results[0].getErrors()[0].getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

`VF Page`

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c" extensions="SendMailClass" sidebar="false" >
   <apex:form>
       <apex:PageBlock>
             <apex:PageBlockButtons location="both" >
               <apex:CommandButton value="Send Mail" action="{!SendMail}"/>
               <apex:CommandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" title="Cancel"/>           
             </apex:PageBlockButtons>
             <apex:pageBlockSection>  
                     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                         <apex:outputText value="Add Attachment : " />
                         <apex:outputPanel >     
                             <apex:inputFile value="{!bl}" filename="{!fileName}" contentType="contentType" title="Add Attachment to Email"/>
                        </apex:outputPanel>   
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
              </apex:pageBlockSection> 
          </apex:PageBlock> 
     </apex:form>             
</apex:page>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: One thing to fix is to change `contentType="contentType"` to `contentType="{!contentType}"`. There is a small chance that is causing the problem.

Comment: @KeithC Thanks for the response..Its typing error i have made..Its contentType="{!contentType}" even it is null.

Comment: @KeithC When i  debug, the FileName and Blob values are null.

Comment: Yeah I can't see what is wrong. You do choose a file first right?

Comment: Yes first choose the file.

Comment: if there was any chance that the inputFile component was not initially rendered and, by user action, later rendered, the inputFile component won't bind the value= attribute to your controller variable

Comment: @NullReferenceException Did you get this to work? i am having the same issue. this same code works as a part of managed package but when i did implement it on a customer org as a normal VF and Apex class its always null.

Comment: @cropredy's suggestion was the issue in my case. I was rendering the inputFile in certain circumstances and this apparently caused it not to bind correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I used your code in my org and it worked. Weird, hah!

The only thing I had is one constructor in the class which was accepting a parameter of type `ApexPages.StandardController`. I didn't find the `filename` and `bl` variable null atleast. Make sure you have the constructor in your class.

Comment: Same here. Above posted code is working for me too. Needed to add parametric constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
public transient Blob bl {get; set;}
```

to this:

```
public Blob bl {get; set;}
```

Transient keyword will not persist values in the view state. This code looks like it is binding `<apex:inputFile value="">` via View State.

Here is example I have used successfully in the past:

http://corycowgill.blogspot.com/2011/01/i-see-lot-of-folks-posting-questions-in.html

Comment: i tried it, but its not working.

Comment: hey did you able to fix this?